Oracle Apex Make row clickable in interactive report
I was wondering if it is possible to make a row clickable,
I have a button to link to a details page but I would like to make it possible to make the row clickable to go to the same page as the button.
I found some old code from the previous person on my project who left where he used dynamic action on page load to trigger a JavaScript code clickable_row('Storno-redenen-beheer',1);
I Tried to make it work on my current page eventtype to go to eventtype-beheer but nothing seems to work.
I tried to make it work with JavaScript as well changing aliases and titles at all items I thought could need it but none of them made it work

Create a dynamic action for the event "Click". Specify the Dynamic Action settings as:
 event scope: dynamic
 static container (Jquery selector): Your IG's static ID
 type: immediate
 event: click
 selection type: Jquery Selector
 Jquery Selector: .a-GV-row[data-id]

Then create a true action -type-Execute Javascript Code
and Javascript code:
//console.log($(this).dataset.id);
var id = this.triggeringElement.dataset.id;
var url = "f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&SESSION."; //example page nr:2
var url1 = '::NO::P2_ITEM' + $v('P1_ITEM'); //--Assigning the parameter value to the corresponding page item
var l = ("javascript:apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&SESSION.").length;
var f = url.slice(0,l)+url1+url.slice(l);
f = f.replace(":::::",":");
window.location.href = f;


Note that the solution above works but does not allow url checksums which impacts security.
